# Output to a file from MS.Win32.TaskScheduler

Tags: c#

I created a task to run a batch file using MS.Win32.TaskScheduler and added an argument to redirect the output to a TXT file, but this method allows the conhost.exe task to stay on which then it prevents the `StreamWriter` to write/append the the same file. I tried Environment.exit(0) it shut down the app completely. Is there any other possible way?

```
td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(location + "\\WindowsRoute.bat", " > online.txt", location));
//Output file >Online.txt
td.Settings.DisallowStartIfOnBatteries = false;

// Register the task in the root folder
ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("Task1", td, TaskCreation.CreateOrUpdate, "SYSTEM", null,
    TaskLogonType.ServiceAccount);
ts.Dispose();

StreamWriter outstream = new StreamWriter(location, append: true);
try
{
    outstream.Write("Workstation is Online on " + DateTime.Now);
    File.SetAttributes(location + "\\online.txt", FileAttributes.Normal);    
}
finally
{
    if (outstream != null)
        outstream.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want to run the batch file, and append text to its output? Is there a reason to use TaskScheduler?

Comment: I need to capture the output from the task scheduler and append the same file to write more in it. Right now after the task write to file its stays opened and locked in way that I can't terminate the app before killing the Conhost task